# How to eliminate rows in a table pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a small script that opens a .csv file with pandas. The file is for houses and their prices, but some houses are marked as 0 sqft and are still priced. This messes up my data, so is there a way to completely remove all rows that have a value of 0 in the sq__ft column? Thanks.

```
digits = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv')

print(tabulate(digits, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

with open('C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv') as i:
    sqft = [int(row["sq__ft"]) for row in DictReader(i)]
    print(sqft)

with open('C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv') as i:
    price = [int(row["price"]) for row in DictReader(i)]
    print(price)
```

Comment: could you please put a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df[df['sqft'] != 0]
```

---

```
df.query("sqft != 0")
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sq__ft':[0,2,3], 'price':[3,4,6]})
print (df)
   price  sq__ft
0      3       0
1      4       2
2      6       3

df1 = df[df['sq__ft'] != 0]
print (df1)
   price  sq__ft
1      4       2
2      6       3

df1 = df.query("sq__ft != 0")
print (df1)

   price  sq__ft
1      4       2
2      6       3
```

EDIT:

If `0` is not `integer`, but `string` add `''`:

```
df1 = df[df['sqft'] != '0']
```

Comment: thanks, but this wont work for some reason. I've added the actual code if you want to see

Comment: And what about `df[df['sqft'] != '0']` ?

Comment: Glad can help! But it seems in column `sqft` are not numeric only values, is it problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = df[~(df.sqft == 0)]
```

or

```
df = df[df.sqft != 0]
```

Here is an example on how these operation work on a reproductible example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,3]], columns=list("AB"))
>>> df 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
>>> 
>>> df[~(df.B == 3)]
   A  B
0  1  2
>>> df[df.B != 3]
   A  B
0  1  2
>>> df[df.B != 3]
```